# What code is needed to export crawled data to .csv?

Tags: python, selenium

Here is the code I've found. This code crawls the Naver map and stores the information in variables.
But I don't know how to view it with a .csv file. I could barely use an already coding finished no-code commodity due to the lack of knowledge of installing dependencies. What code is needed to the entire code's work finished, exporting crawled data to a .csv file? Especially exporting reviews that are on the list will be tricky to express in .csv IMO.

---

Source
https://velog.io/@kws04254/Selenium-BeautilfulSoup4%EB%A5%BC-%EC%9D%B4%EC%9A%A9%ED%95%9C-%EB%84%A4%EC%9D%B4%EB%B2%84-%EC%A7%80%EB%8F%84-%ED%81%AC%EB%A1%A4%EB%A7%81

---

```
    !pip install pandas
    !pip install selenium
    !pip install webdriver-manager
    !pip install beautifulsoup4

    import selenium #selenium
    import pandas as pd #pandas to read csv and use dataframe
    from selenium import webdriver #webdriver to launch and control the browser
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys #for keying into the browser
    To find tags using from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By #webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait #for Explicitly wait
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager #Necessary when installing Chrome Web Driver for crawling in Chrome
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC #For checking the status of certain elements in the browser
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #to import and parse browser tags
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException #Exceptions for exception handling

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get("https://map.naver.com/v5/")
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "input_search"))
        ) #Wait until the input window appears
    finally:
        pass

    search_box = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"input_search")
    search_box.send_keys(keyword)
    search_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    #Actions based on search results

    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"button_clear").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    def checkIsList(checkCount):
         try:
             driver.switch_to.default_content()
             WebDriverWait(driver,1.5).until(
             EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, searchFrame))
             )
             driver.switch_to.frame(searchFrame)
             WebDriverWait(driver,1).until(
                 EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, resultListTitleClass))
             )
             driver.switch_to.default_content()
             return 0;
         except TimeoutException:
             # When you move directly to restaurant information from search results
             try:
                 driver.switch_to.default_content()
                 WebDriverWait(driver,1.5).until(
                 EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, entryFrame))
                 )
                 driver.switch_to.frame(entryFrame)
                 WebDriverWait(driver,1).until(
                     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, resultTargetTitleDiv))
                 )
                 driver.switch_to.default_content()
                 return 1
             # When there are no search results
             except TimeoutException:
                
                 # If it is the first time, reorganize the search term and search
                 if(checkCount==0):
                     return 2
                 # Even after reorganizing the search term, there is no store without it
                 elif(checkCount==1):
                     return 3

    WebDriverWait(driver,1).until(
                 EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, resultListTitleClass))
             )

             for i in range(2):
                 search(flag)
                 checkResult = checkIsList(i)
                 if checkResult == 0: #results as a list
                     #todo
                     # Check if it is correct, proceed with crawling if correct, otherwise
                     # select
                     driver.switch_to.default_content()
                     driver.switch_to.frame(searchFrame)
                     #driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,resultTitleClick).click()
                     driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,resultTitleClick).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                     driver.switch_to.default_content()
                     WebDriverWait(driver,4).until(
                     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, entryFrame))
                     )
                     driver.switch_to.frame(entryFrame)
                     getInfo(row)
                     driver.switch_to.default_content()
                     break
                 elif checkResult ==1: #The result is directly displayed as restaurant information
                     # Get information right away
                     driver.switch_to.default_content()
                     WebDriverWait(driver,4).until(
                         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, entryFrame))
                     )
                     driver.switch_to.frame(entryFrame)
                     getInfo(row)
                     break
                 elif checkResult ==2: # First time, no result
                     flag = False
                     continue
                 elif checkResult ==3: # No result even after the second time
                     data.loc[idx,"review"] = "noResult"
                     print(str(idx)+". "+data.loc[idx,"Company name"]+"

         html = driver. page_source
         soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
         address = soup.find("span",addressSpan).text
         day = soup.find_all("span",daySpan)
         time = soup.find_all("div",timeDiv)

             driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, reviewTabOpenerSelector).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
             WebDriverWait(driver,2).until(
                 EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, reviewSpan))
             )
             reviewOpeners = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,reviewOpenerA)
             for opener in reviewOpeners:
                 #opener. click()
                 opener.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
             html = driver. page_source`
             soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
             reviews = soup.find_all("span",reviewSpan)
```

---

All the instruction is in the first URL (Source).

I tried nothing but reading the article and finding it will be useful for me
I found pandas should be used to handle .csv files.

Comment: probably a duplicate question, since it sounds like you're simply asking how to export a dataframe to a csv: [df.to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: It has a tricky part to make in my narrow sight. It should express multiple reviews in rows while not touching other rows. And I need all the possible results the crawler crawled but not knowing how. I think the fastest learning way is to make a product asap(somehow) and then learn the other parts of the languages. Please kindly let me wait for the detailed answer. Thank you for the link though. I'll definitely check it when I'm able to understand it.